# Usar datos devueltos por $http en el controlador en AngularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs, clausuras

Mi problema es que hago una petición por `$http` para recuperar unos datos que necesito usar en mi controlador, el problema es que si hago un `console.log` fuera con la variable asignada a los datos me marca `undefined`.

Quería saber si existe alguna forma de poder usar los datos de ese `$scope` sin estar dentro del `then` del `$http`.

Ejemplo:

```
$http.get(config.root + 'index/trlang/'+lang).success(
    function(data){ $rootScope.trlang = data['lang'];}
);
console.log($rootScope.trlang); // undefined
```

Esto es a la hora de ejecutar el controlador, en la vista se muestran los datos correctamente, pero en el controlador no puedo usar esos datos ya que las peticiones, se cargan en última instancia.

Comment: la función `$http.get` es asíncrona? probablemente el `console.log` se ejecute antes que se asigne la variable `$rootScope.trlang`.

Answer (score 1):

Obviamente que se puede.

Simplemente hay que hacer una ***retrollamada (callback)*** al terminar la solicitud *HTTP*.

```
ejecutarEstaFuncion = function(data){
    // en esta parte puedes usar data como desees.
}
$http.get(config.root + 'index/trlang/'+lang).success(
   function(data){
      ejecutarEstaFuncion(data);
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

También puedes hacerlo previo a que cargue el controlador, con la función `resolve` en `ui-router` como `ngRoute`.

Por ejemplo:

`ui-router` y/o `ngRoute`:

```
/*En ui-router*/
$stateProvider
    .state('exampleState', {
        url: '/exampleState',
        controller: "ExampleCtrl",
        resolve:{
            getData: function($q, $http){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.get(config.root + 'index/trlang/'+lang)
                    .success(function(data) {
                        return deferred.resolve(data);
                    })
                    .error(function(error, code) {
                        return deferred.reject(null);
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }
)
/*En ngRoute*/
$routeProvider
    .when("/exampleState", {
        controller: "ExampleCtrl",
        resolve:{
            getData: function($q, $http){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.get(config.root + 'index/trlang/'+lang)
                    .success(function(data) {
                        return deferred.resolve(data);
                    })
                    .error(function(error, code) {
                        return deferred.reject(null);
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }
)
```

En controlador:

```
/*Controlador*/
angular.module("app")
    .controller("ExampleCtrl", function (getData) {
        console.log(getData);
    }
);
```